# AJAX.NET error only affecting certain users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, ajax

I have a couple of users who are reporting "**ASP.NET AJAX client-side framework (ScriptResource.axd) failed to load**" error on some of our SharePoint pages.

1. Only affecting certain uses, majority get no errors
2. The error is isolated to certain user accounts: user A may get the error, but user B (on the same workstation) can load the page successfully.
3. Only affecting IE (multiple versions: IE9, IE10, and IE11); pages load successfully in other browsers on the same client, same user.

It seems to me like maybe a caching issue in IE.  I have tried deleting all temporary internet files, cookies, browsing history, etc but that did not resolve the error.  I also ran the repair tool on .NET 4 Client profile, no change.  Anyone else experience this and have a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing all browser setting from IE resolved this;

Setting (gear) -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset.  Check the box to clear all data.